# Запуск программы через web-браузер

Tags: php

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать ссылку в браузере, чтобы при клике на нее открывалась необходимая программа (моя игра)?

Comment: А игра уже установлена на машине клиента?

Comment: Да установлена

Comment: А может ТС имеет в виду просто то, что ему нужно PHP-игру запустить? Тогда надо Apache + PHP, может быть MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Не нужно придумывать костыли, всё уже придумано до нас.
Нужно [поработать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389223) с [регистром](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx). Так делает Steam, например.

Answer (score 3):

Если игра установлена на машине клиента, то надо придумывать костыль.
Можно, например, сделать Java Web Start приложение, состоящее из одной строчки:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your game");
```

Чтобы пользователь не видел заставки с логотипом Оракл, используйте опцию `-silent` при создании кешей. То есть первой командой создаете кеш "тихо", второй командой запускаете.

По-другому, наверное, существуют решения для конкретных браузеров.